# Little-o algebra

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are both $o(n)$ functions,  that is the following is satisfied:

For every $\epsilon, \bar{\epsilon}>0$ $\; \exists \;N , \bar{N}\;$ s.t.

$$ |f(n)| < \epsilon|n|,\;n>N$$
  $$ |g(n)| < \bar{\epsilon}|n|,\;n>\bar{N}.$$

Then is $f(n)-g(n)$ also $o(n)$?

And if so, how would you prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)=o(n)$ iff $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}=0.$$ You can now use the standard rules for limits.

Comment: Of course! Thank you.